# solve the recurrence relation $a_{n+2}-6a_{n+1}+9a_n=3(2^n)+7{n \choose 3}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

### $$a_{n+2}-6a_{n+1}+9a_n=3(2^n)+7{n \choose 3} , a_2=4,a_1=1,n\ge3$$

my try:

(1) $a_n=a^{h}_n+a^{p}_n$

(2) solving homogeous part: $x^2-6x+9=0$ so $x=3$. then we have $a^{h}_n=(k_1+nk_2)3^n$.

(3) solving particular part: suppose $a_n=A2^n$ then $4A-12A+9A=3+7\frac{{n \choose 3}}{2^n}$ so $a^{p}_n=3(2^n)+7{n \choose 3}$.

(4) finding $k_1$ and $k_2$: $a_n=(k_1+nk_2)3^n+3(2^n)+7{n \choose 3}$

$a_1=1=(k_1+k_2)3+6+7{1 \choose 3}$ and $a_2=4=(k_1+2k_2)9+12+7{2 \choose 3}$ but I don't know ${1 \choose 3}$ and ${2 \choose 3}$.

what should I do?

Comment: Are they not just binomial coefficients?

Comment: yes, but how calculate them?

Comment: Normally they are defined as $0$

Comment: so $k_1=-\frac{22}{9}$ and $k_2=\frac{7}{9}$ and did i solve the it  correct (recurrence relation)?

Comment: I think your step (3) is all wrong.

Comment: so what is the correct way?

Comment: Try [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

Comment: The particular solution must take into account the binomial as well as the exponential. It must look like $A2^n+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E$.

Comment: Understood, Elsa?

Comment: Please, Elsa, respond.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has lost interest.